# Magento 2 - remove postcode field on checkout

Tags: magento2

I have issues on removing the checkout postcode field on a default Magento 2.1 install.

I have tried by adding the `componentDisabled` node on the `jsLayout` object for the `postcode` component:

Created a new module with the following structure:

```
/
|etc
|___module.xml
|view
|___frontend
|______layout
|_________checkout_index_index.xml
|registration.php
```

The `app/code/<VENDOR>/<MODULE>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode_test" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item> 
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

By inspecting the json returned by `$block->getJsLayout()` [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml#L21), I find that the `postcode` node is overwritten by the one on the `Magento_Checkout` ([this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml#L208)) module and the componentDisabled node from my module isn't used.

I am also noticing that my `postcode_test` note appears in this json.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Heres an alternative way to do this. I use this same approach to remove the phone number field.

We need to make a plugin for the `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` class defined as follows:

```
class DummyZip
{
    public function afterGetPostcode()
    {
        return '00000';
    }
}
```

This eliminates the need to change all the validation. A dummy value is used that will bypass all that.

Now to hide the field, we extend the `checkout_index_index.xml` layout like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/checkout.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Finally, we'll also want to remove the field from the billing address form (if customer has different billing and shipping addresses).
Create a plugin for the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor` class with this content:

```
class Process
{

    public function afterProcess($subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                 ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as &$child)
        {
            unset($child['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']);
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will just hide the field and use the dummy value instead removing all the validators, smart.   Thanks!

Comment: how do you edit the Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address class?

Comment: You make a plugin http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Hello, From billing address its not still removing

Comment: We are using the same way, but after upgrading to Magento 2.4.4, this is not working, have you checked this in Magento 2.4.4?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to remove the postcode field. It cannot be done via jsLayout approach because it's dynamically created from EAV attributes on the LayoutProcessor class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php#L68

So in order to accomplish this, we need to:

1. Remove it from checkout form

Here we need to set is_user_defined to 1 for the postcode eav_attribute. I recommed doing this via a setup resource, like this:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $setup->startSetup();

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'postcode');
    $attribute->setIsUserDefined(1)->save();

    $attribute->save();
}
```

2. Disable the postcode validators

We have to disable 4 validators located under the following classes:

a) Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface, _validate() method.

- I did this by extending the save() and _validate() methods via inheritance.

b) Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Validator\Postcode, isValid() method.

c) Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Data\Postcode, validate() method.

d) Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress, validateValue() method.

- I extended this last three methods via Plugin afterMethod.

After doing this you should be able to place an order without the postcode field.

I have also created a much detailed step by step tutorial here: 
http://serbu.me/2016/10/01/how-to-remove-postcode-field-from-magento2-checkout

Comment: i had tried in magento 2.2.6  your step by step tutorial.. still pincode textfield not gone from checkout :(

Comment: HI @Florin I am facing the issue after removing the postcode