# magento 2 / override core code

Tags: magento2, php, xml

i need to delete "zip code" text field from cehckout page in magento 2. For that i following this answers:
[ANSWER](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138958) but i don't know how to add my class which will set default value '00000' for "zip code" text field and don't know how to override code xml in own plugin. I created own plugin, please tell me what i doing wrong in building own plugin.

**Folders tree:**

```
  --/app/code/Rockforweb/CheckoutZipcode
  --Data/
    --Address.php
  --etc/
    --di.xml
    --module.xml
  --view/
    --frontend/
      --page_layout/
        --checkout_index_index.xml
  --composer.json
  --registration.php
```

**FILES CONTENT:**

registration.php:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Rockforweb_CheckoutZipcode',
    __DIR__
);
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Rockforweb\/CheckoutZipcode",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.1.2",
    "license": [
        "Proprietary"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Rockforweb\\CheckoutZipcode\\": ""
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Rockforweb\/CheckoutZipcode"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

checkout_index_index.xml:

[checkout_index_index.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138958)

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address"
                 type="Rockforweb\CheckoutZipcode\Data\Address" />
</config>
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rockforweb_CheckoutZipcode" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Quote" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Address.php:

```
<?php
namespace Rockforweb\CheckoutZipcode\Data;

class CheckoutZipcode extends Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address
{
    public function afterGetPostcode()
    {
        return '00000';
    }
}
```

Comment: are you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Page layout` to `Layout`

```
--view/
 --frontend/
  --layout/
    --checkout_index_index.xml
```

And Change `Address.php` class name to `Address`

```
class Address extends Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address
{
    public function afterGetPostcode()
    {
        return '00000';
    }
}
```

Then, Clear cache and check it.