# How to remove or disable street address and city fields from shipping address in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

Is there any solution disable or remove the **city and street fields** from `checkout_index_index.xml`?

Thanks

Comment: kindly check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138958/60921

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in checkout_index_index.xml

```
 <item name="city" xsi:type="array"> <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item> </item>
```

Comment: It doesn't help because I think that the address and city fields are required column  in the database

Comment: I think to hide via CSS, and giving them the default value, but is not a normal solution for this, how do this via another solutions ?