# How to remove zip/postal code in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1

I want to know how to remove **Zip/postal** code from the customer checkout page form in Magento 2?

Comment: you can follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138454/magento-2-remove-postcode-field-on-checkout/138958  it may useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom module with just following 1 file or can add this line to any module less file.

> view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less

```
div[name$=".postcode"] {
    display: none;
}
```

After this, just make postal code as optional field from admin panel.

> Store -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Country Options -> "Zip/Postal Code is Optional for"

Here uncheck "Use System Value" checkbox and select all countries.